# How to use lag functionality on columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame with in wide format with around 100,000+ rows and 700+ columns. I need to compute individual column as a ratio of its immediate preceding column. The following simulates my problem

```
df = data.frame(
        name = c("c1", "c2", "c3"), 
        m12 = c(50, 150, 200), 
        m23 = c(100, 180, 120), 
        m37 = c(150, 414, 180)
      )
```

The desired output data frame (dfo) will be

```
  name m12  r2 r3
1   c1  50 2.0  1.5
2   c2 150 1.2  2.3
3   c3 200 0.6  1.5
```

where

```
dfo$r2 = df$m23/df$m12
dfo$r3 = df$m37/df$m23
```

What I need is to identify is for a given column position getting previous column and using it to compute the ratio. Using a for loop, I can get what I am looking for, but that is not "The R way" of doing things.

How can I get the R-ish solution? My preference will be using tidyverse or base R way, but I am open to other approaches too. It should work in a generalized way on a data frame with any number of rows or columns with the given structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the columns using `lapply` and then bind them to the existing data.frame.

```
dfo = cbind(df, lapply(3:ncol(df), function(i) df[,i]/df[,i-1]))
names(dfo)[5:6] = c("r2", "r3")
dfo
  name m12 m23 m37  r2  r3
1   c1  50 100 150 2.0 1.5
2   c2 150 180 414 1.2 2.3
3   c3 200 120 180 0.6 1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with basic R like this:

```
df = data.frame(
    name = c("c1", "c2", "c3"),
    m12 = c(50, 150, 200),
    m23 = c(100, 180, 120),
    m37 = c(150, 414, 180)
)

# Get the index of all columns that start with "m"
z = which(grepl("^m",colnames(df)))

# calculate the proportion to the previous column
proportions = df[,z[-1]]/df[,z[-length(z)]]
```

Result:

```
> proportions
  m23 m37
1 2.0 1.5
2 1.2 2.3
3 0.6 1.5
```

After calculating the new columns change their name accordingly with `colnames`

```
newName = paste0("r",2:length(z))
colnames(proportions) = newName

> proportions
   r2  r3
1 2.0 1.5
2 1.2 2.3
3 0.6 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this tidyverse-way, you should `gather()` the columns into rows first:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

df = data.frame(
  name = c("c1", "c2", "c3"), 
  m12 = c(50, 150, 200), 
  m23 = c(100, 180, 120), 
  m37 = c(150, 414, 180)
)

df_gathered <- gather(df, "key", "value", starts_with("m"))

df_gathered
#>   name key value
#> 1   c1 m12    50
#> 2   c2 m12   150
#> 3   c3 m12   200
#> 4   c1 m23   100
#> 5   c2 m23   180
#> 6   c3 m23   120
#> 7   c1 m37   150
#> 8   c2 m37   414
#> 9   c3 m37   180
```

Then, you can use `lag()` as you usually do because columns are rows now. Though my code might be not smart enough here, it should easier to work with this form of data if you are familiar with wrangling rows:

```r
df_normalized <- df_gathered %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(value_normalized =  value / lag(value),
         # treat the first item (m12) differently
         key   = if_else(is.na(value_normalized), key,   paste0("r", row_number() - 1L)),
         value = if_else(is.na(value_normalized), value, value_normalized)) %>%
  select(-value_normalized)

df_normalized
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   name [3]
#>     name   key value
#>   <fctr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     c1   m12  50.0
#> 2     c2   m12 150.0
#> 3     c3   m12 200.0
#> 4     c1    r1   2.0
#> 5     c2    r1   1.2
#> 6     c3    r1   0.6
#> 7     c1    r2   1.5
#> 8     c2    r2   2.3
#> 9     c3    r2   1.5
```

Lastly, if needed, the data can be `spread()`ed into the column-wide form.

```r
spread(df_normalized, key, value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   name [3]
#>     name   m12    r1    r2
#> * <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     c1    50   2.0   1.5
#> 2     c2   150   1.2   2.3
#> 3     c3   200   0.6   1.5
```

Comment: @ycw Oops... Thanks for pointing out! I've mistakenly flipped `value / lag(value)` to `lag(value) / value`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

we can use functions from `dplyr` and `purrr`. The idea is to convert the data frame to a list an conduct the operation, and then convert it back to data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df2 <- df %>% select(-name)

df3 <- map2_dfc(df2[-1], df2[-ncol(df2)], ~.x/.y) %>%
  setNames(paste0("r", 2:ncol(df2)))

df4 <- bind_cols(df, df3)
df4
#   name m12 m23 m37  r2  r3
# 1   c1  50 100 150 2.0 1.5
# 2   c2 150 180 414 1.2 2.3
# 3   c3 200 120 180 0.6 1.5
```

Or a solution from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. It uses `gather` to convert the data frame from wide-format to long-format, use `mutate` and `lag` to calculate the value, and then re-arrange the column. Finally, convert it back to wide-format. `df3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  gather(M, value1, -name) %>%
  arrange(name, M) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(value2 = value1/lag(value1)) %>%
  mutate(R = paste0("r", 1:n()))

df3 <- bind_rows(df2 %>% select(name, column = M, value = value1),
                 df2 %>% select(name, column = R, value = value2)) %>%
  drop_na(value) %>%
  spread(column, value)
df3

# # A tibble: 3 x 6
# # Groups:   name [3]
#     name   m12   m23   m37    r2    r3
# * <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     c1    50   100   150   2.0   1.5
# 2     c2   150   180   414   1.2   2.3
# 3     c3   200   120   180   0.6   1.5
```